# Why doesn't this image link (HTML <img> tag within <a> tag) work?

Tags: html

I'm just learning HTML on my own, and saw [this example](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_link_image) from w3schools.

Out of curiosity, I changed the href property of the  tag from `"http://www.w3schools.com"` to something like `"http://www.google.com"`, or `"http://www.facebook.com"`, and then the image link just won't work anymore (nothing happens when I click on the image).

I also tried copying and pasting the exact code and changing the href field [in JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/23p1ofgf/) --same thing (except the local image doesn't display anymore).

Comment: This work correctly, only you've to close the `<img>` tag. http://jsfiddle.net/23p1ofgf/1/

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/23p1ofgf/  -- Fiddle doesn't let you modify the URL directly, by changing target="_blank" will allow you to continue learning HTML using JSFiddle.

Comment: It's a security prevention to stop anybody pretending to be facebook or google.

Comment: Always include relevant code in our answer and there are much better learning resources than w3schools (http://www.w3fools.com/)

Comment: @Ferrrmolina: I tried your updated Fiddle, but it's till not working (I use Chrome)

Comment: @Ferrrmolina: HTML5 (noted by defining `<!DOCTYPE html>`) doesn't require the [img](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/img) tag to have the `/>` suffix. jsFiddle's parser just hasn't been updated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're actually observing your browser protecting you, believe it or not.

If you're inclined to know why, have a read: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/X-Frame-Options

Put simply, the content (because it's part of a different domain name) is being blocked. This is keep you saf(er) by disallowing content from another domain within an iframe (and other objects).

To put it in context, imagine visiting facebook and clicking on a link. That link loaded a page from another website that looked like facebook (but really wasn't) but you continued on and provided details about yourself. By blanking out the page you can feel a bit safer knowing you never left facebook's website (or if/when you did, the content was blocked).

As for why it works in the *original* example, w3schools is linking to their own website *from* their own website. If you want to play with it, use a link to another resource on the page (such as http://www.w3schools.com/html/default.asp)